# Fans run after Macbook Pro lid is shut

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

The fans in my MBP will continue to run for a minute or two after I close the lid. This is frustrating because I often want to close it and immediately put it away in its soft zipper case but I don't want to put it in the case while it's still spitting out hot air. Any ideas why the fans don't turn off immediately (or within like 15 seconds)? This started happening after I upgraded to 10.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typically happens when the CPU has been working and the system needs to push more hot air out. I think the firmware within the machine manages this but I'm not quite sure. My air does it and I just put it away anyway. I've never experienced anything bad with it.

Comment: your right thats normal cause the new OS uses a lot more CPU - but you should give the device time to cool down - putting it away is ok but take care of not covering the air-slices at the back. It would also bee good to go to an Apple-Store/Retailer and let them have a look inside the Device maybe its full of dust e.g.

Comment: With Mountain Lion it would just turn off the fans and stay hot. I do give it a bit of time to cool but for the most part it isn't an issue for me.

Comment: Alright good to know. I was curious because I didn't notice it doing this (but maybe it always has) before I upgraded to Mavericks. It is probably about time to hit it with the air canister and clear out dust (it's been a few years since I've had it open)